# Converting Curl command line to python

Tags: python, json, curl, python-requests, fiware-orion

I am using the Fiware Orion Context Broker and I want to POST some data using a python script. The command line (which works fine) looks like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Fiware-ServicePath: /orion" -H "Fiware-Service: orion" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id": "JetsonTX1", "type": "sensor",  "title": {"type": "Text","value": "Init"}, "percentage": { "type": "Text", "value": "0%"}}' "http://141.39.159.63:1026/v2/entities/"
```

My Python script:

```
import requests
import json


url = 'http://141.39.159.63:1026/v2/entities/'
data = '''{
      "title": {
        "value": "demo",
        "type": "Text"
      },
          "percentage": {
        "type": "Text",
        "value": "0%"            
       }'''
data_json = json.dumps(data)
headers = {"Accept": "application/json", "Fiware-ServicePath": "/bonseyes", "Fiware-Service": "bonseyes", "Content-Type": "application/json"}

response = requests.post(url, data=data_json, headers=headers)

print(response.json())
```

This is what response.json() returns:

```
{u'description': u'Errors found in incoming JSON buffer', u'error': u'ParseError'}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Did my edited answer resolved your issue?

Comment: Almost! I had to use: `response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)` instead of `response = requests.post(url, json=data_json, headers=headers)`
Thanks a lot!

Comment: please mark the answer if it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should not pass data as string like so:

```
data = '''{
      "title": {
        "value": "demo",
        "type": "Text"
      },
          "percentage": {
        "type": "Text",
        "value": "0%"            
       }'''
```

Pass it as normal dict:

```
data = {
      "title": {
        "value": "demo",
        "type": "Text"
      },
          "percentage": {
        "type": "Text",
        "value": "0%"            
       }}
```

The request library will automatically convert this dictionary for you. Also make sure you want to use the `data` parameter and not the `json`. Below expert from the documentation should clear out why.

```
def post(url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs):
   r"""Sends a POST request.

   :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
   :param data: (optional) Dictionary (will be form-encoded), bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
   :param json: (optional) json data to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
    :param \*\*kwargs: Optional arguments that ``request`` takes.
    :return: :class:`Response <Response>` object
    :rtype: requests.Response
"""
```

From your comment it seems you should pass your data like so:

`response = requests.post(url, json=data_json, headers=headers)`

Because your endpoint requires json and not form-encoded bytes

And there is also missing curly brace at the end.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out here. I tried what you suggested, which led to following error:
`{u'description': u'entity id length: 0, min length supported: 1', u'error': u'BadRequest'}`

Comment: Check my edit if your endpoint requires a json data you should use `json` parameter instead of `data`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should try using keyValues option for OCB. It will make your payload way shorter. I use similar python program for updating values, therefore PATCH request in my approach:

```
    #Sorting out url and payload for request
    data = '{"' + attribute + '":' + value + '}'
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

    url = urlOfOCB + '/v2/entities/' + entityId + '/attrs?options=keyValues'
    r = requests.patch(url, (data), headers=headers)
```

You can read about this option [here](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user/walkthrough_apiv2/). As I can see you are not defining any new type for your attributes, therefore it will be "Text" by default, while using keyValues.

Attribute/metadata type may be omitted in requests. When omitted in attribute/metadata creation or in update operations, a default is used for the type depending on the value:

- If value is a string, then type Text is used
- If value is a number, then type Number is used.
- If value is a boolean, then type Boolean is used.
- If value is an object or array, then StructuredValue is used.
- If value is null, then None is used.

More on those things you can find [here](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/).